# Google Cloud Storage API - StringToSign returned wrong bucket name

Tags: storage, google-docs-api

I am trying to upload to my cloud storage using a signed url.
I had plenty of errors trying to sign the string correctly.
What I dont understand is the  object which always "www.google.com" prefixing my "bucketName + objectName"

**Request**

```
    curl --location --request PUT 'https://storage.googleapis.com/ABCD/disney.png?GoogleAccessId=cjl-scheduler-storage@cjl-scheduler.iam.gserviceaccount.com&Expires=1604702284&Signature=l37cl4a6lmX6AiQ%2BTi3%2FkZqm9vH0bXSYbZf4XNTwvvQKjJRdEIrEHrf55Yvci5ROso2av4krnvS7XXdaetWCFNT0oRdU%2BAGlF%2BD%2F2BZls%2BB072MP%2B8LXuvqOPCyBJWmaNcEB35%2Brv5FzM1fe7zuI7XxGF3kW6uCWjWU8%2BkMwJGBz1JeXytHErhxsjGpciBzllL5j0G9nwtHc7TbgZNaYGOUAjpjXS7NJzLCm4JQh2%2BYarvthpDzim25FRB818cKeegIFeZyy2FSi2MjfdmriVwVJbvTNvceF%2B5uXnwWcqQU9ZVIXmFNzsJq5m1eHO4zQ9HvkpSUCKtzEH3SL5Mx6uA%3D%3D' \
    --header 'Content-Type: image/png' \
    --data-binary '@/Users/manueldupont/Downloads/disney.png'
```

**Response**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<Error>
    <Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code>
    <Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your Google secret key and signing method.</Message>
    <StringToSign>PUT

image/png
1604702284
/www.google.com/ABCD/disney.png</StringToSign>
</Error>
```

Looks like storage.googleapis.com concatenate this to the object I pass. Why is that ?!

Here is the code I use to sign

```
 String url_signature = signString(key,
                verb + "\n\n" +
                        "image/png" + "\n" +
                        expirationSeconds + "\n" +
                        bucketName + "/" + objectName);
        String signed_url = "https://storage.googleapis.com/" + bucketName + "/" + objectName +
                "?GoogleAccessId=" + ((ServiceAccountCredentials) this.getCreds()).getClientEmail() +
                "&Expires=" + expirationSeconds +
                "&Signature=" + URLEncoder.encode(url_signature, "UTF-8");
```

knowing that bucketName="ABCD" and objectName="disney.png".

Comment: To get the information you need, can you tell me more about how you see the response being concatenated to your object?

Comment: So, i found my error. The bucket was not “public”. I set the right permission and i was able to upload but still, i think the error handling could be better. The error i got was the one i had in my post. with the “/www.google.com/ABCD/disney.png”. While my bucket is ABCD.  So that was pretty confusing. At first, it looked like a “wrong bucket name error”, but it was not.